# how I can write this condition in javascript(Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, calculator

i recently start a calculator project with react.
I create the project and it works fine but i just wanna add a new feature to it.
i wanna when i click on a operation symbol **(like "+", "-", "*", "/")** if i click one more time and the operation that exist before that be the same **(for example 1234+)** when i click on "+" or "-" my code don't add it to the code and replace it with the before operation and also do that to "/" and "*"

I also attach the repository link so you can see my calculator source code by yourself. [the repository of project source code](https://github.com/arviinmo/Calculator)

Comment: The question needs to be improved. Try to ask only the specific problem that you are facing, instead of just linking your code and asking why it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `handleClick` function simply check if the current character is an operator symbol (e.g: '+','-','*','/') and the last character in the current `result` string is also an operator symbol. If they are both operator symbols simply do the following:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if (result.length > 0 && (result[result.length - 1] === '+' || result[result.length - 1] === '-' || result[result.length - 1] === '*' || result[result.length - 1] === '/') && (e.target.name === '+' || e.target.name === '-' || e.target.name === '*' || e.target.name === '/')) {
    const newRes = result.slice(0, result.length - 1).concat(e.target.name);
    setResult(newRes);
  } else {
    setResult(result.concat(e.target.name));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update handleClick function like below:

```
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        if(result.length && result.charAt(result.length-1) != e.target.name || result.length == 0)
        setResult(result.concat(e.target.name));   
}
```

Comment: that's not working!:(

Comment: https://github.com/corasphinx/Calculator.git
I forked your repo and tested in my side.

Comment: Here is App.js
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QKuBxOWjUnqkLhk7O6q3G8Ai8cWdc0Yt-KhQ0VHd824/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry, you're right.